# What happened if I dont check if an object was initialized in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

I have a program that I would love to get help to fully understand.

XYPoint.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface XYPoint : NSObject
@property float x, y;
-(void) setX: (float)xVal setY: (float)yVal;
@end
```

XYPoint.m:

```
#import "XYPoint.h"
@implementation XYPoint
@synthesize x, y;

-(void) setX:(float)xVal setY:(float)yVal
{
    x = xVal;
    y = yVal;
}
@end
```

Rectangle.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class XYPoint;
@interface Rectangle: NSObject
@property float width, height, tx, ty;

-(XYPoint *) origin;
-(void) setOrigin: (XYPoint *) pt;
-(void) translate: (XYPoint *) point;
@end
```

Rectangle.m:

```
#import "Rectangle.h"
#import "XYPoint.h"

@implementation Rectangle
{
    XYPoint *origin;
}
@synthesize width, height, tx, ty;
-(void) setWidth: (float) w andHeight: (float) h
{
    width = w;
    height = h;
}

-(void) translate:(XYPoint *)point
{
    tx = origin.x + point.x;
    ty = origin.y + point.y;
}

-(void)setOrigin:(XYPoint *)pt
{
    //if (!origin)
     //  origin = [[XYPoint alloc] init];
    origin.x = pt.x;
    origin.y = pt.y;
}

-(XYPoint *) origin
{
    return origin;
}
@end
```

main:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "XYPoint.h"
#import "Rectangle.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool
    {

        Rectangle *myRect = [[Rectangle alloc] init];
        XYPoint *vector = [[XYPoint alloc] init];
        XYPoint *origin = [[XYPoint alloc] init];

        [origin setX:10 setY:15];
        [myRect setOrigin:origin];

        [vector setX:30 setY:50];

        [myRect translate:vector];
        NSLog(@"%f , %f", myRect.tx, myRect.ty);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the Rectangle implementation there is a `if (!origin)` to test if the origin object was initialized, and if not, it will allocate and initialize it. I dont understand why when im using this test I get the right answer, and when not, i'm not getting the right answer..\
Could someone please explain a total newbie what is going on there?
tnx

Comment: "origin" is just a pointer, not an object.  Until it's initialized, there is no "there" there.

Comment: Because using the test, you are creating an XYPoint object (allocating and initialing it) and assigning its address to the XYPoint ptr. Without doing this, XYPoint *origin is of undefined value (which means by doing to origin.x and origin.y assignment you are probably stomping other data, or crashing.  You could optionally implement the init method for Rectangle to it alloc's and init's origin at that time, then you wouldn't need to do the test.

Comment: @DavidHope thanks allot david for the detailed and great answer :)

Comment: @DavidHope since `origin` is a class member it will be set to `nil` when the class is initialized, therefore, no stomping of other data will occur. Though variables are typically useless until initialized.

Comment: @Joe sorry, too much C++ in my background. I didn't know exactly how Objective-C initializes, and my Mac is at home, so couldn't test it.

Comment: Objective C initializes pretty much the same as C++ for a `sometype*` pointer, which is to say, not at all (with the exception that instance vars are zeroed, something that's not a given in C++).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You answered it in your question:

> if (!origin) to test if the origin object was initialized, and if not,
>   it will allocate and initialize it

The `if (!origin)` is for [lazy initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization) and if you do not initialize it it will remain `nil`. Objective-C allows you to message `nil` without any result, so if you never initialize origin `origin.x = pt.x;` and `origin.y = pt.y;` does nothing and all of you math operations that rely on origin will use `0.0`.

Comment: quick question: in this particular case i presented, isn't `XYPoint *origin = [[XYPoint alloc] init];` in the main is allocating and initialize origin? and if i dont use the test `(!origin)`, im not suppose to get the right answer? @Joe

Comment: That allocates an `origin` inside of `main` completely unrelated to the origin inside of `Rectangle`. You are just copying the origin you created in main to the origin in `Rectangle`.